# Transform table with custom UDF and save the result in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for a way how to transform a table and save the result to another table in Snowflake. While transforming the table I want to modify some columns using a UDF and then save the result into interim table.

```
Steps:
1) read tableA 
2) transform tableA (change some columns using custom UDF) 
3) save result to tableB
```

Is it possible to do that on Snowflake side?

*UPD*

TableA

```
+----------+---------+--------------------------+---------------+--------+--------+-----+
|first_name|last_name|email                     |address        |address2|address3|dob  |
+----------+---------+--------------------------+---------------+--------+--------+-----+
|Mike      |Johnson  |mike@gmail.com            |1650 Jackson St|Apt 704 |null    |09/10|
|John      |Dunn     |john101@gmail.com         |320 Day St     |null    |null    |01/20|
|Bill      |Rinitin  |rinitin@gmail.com         |108 Marietta Dr|null    |null    |04/11|
|Chris     |Talbot   |chris2@gmail.com          |401 Harrison St|null    |null    |07/17|
|Teresa    |Middleton|teresa.middleton@yahoo.com|181 Fremont St |Unit 62C|null    |11/21|
+----------+---------+--------------------------+---------------+--------+--------+-----+
```

TableB

```
+----------+---------+--------------------------+---------------+--------+--------+-----+
|first_name|last_name|email                     |address        |address2|address3|dob  |
+----------+---------+--------------------------+---------------+--------+--------+-----+
|M***      |J******  |m***@gmail.com            |108 Marietta Dr|null    |null    |09/**|
|J***      |D***     |j******@gmail.com         |181 Fremont St |Unit 62C|null    |01/**|
|B***      |R******  |r******@gmail.com         |1650 Jackson St|Apt 704 |null    |04/**|
|C****     |T*****   |c*****@gmail.com          |320 Day St     |null    |null    |07/**|
|T*****    |M********|te****.*********@yahoo.com|401 Harrison St|null    |null    |11/**|
+----------+---------+--------------------------+---------------+--------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: It's possible and done frequently, but we'll need an sample input data and intended output data to be in a position to say it's possible in this particular case.

Comment: I updated my question with table transformation details.

Comment: For what you're looking to do, I highly recommend Snowflake's Dynamic Data Masking: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-column-ddm-use.html

Comment: @GregPavlik I'll read it. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use INSERT INTO… SELECT…

This is standard SQL and nothing specific to Snowflake

Answer (score 0):

If the transformation is permanent (i.e. the original data is fine to be lost), `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` (CTAS) or `INSERT SELECT` would be a good option.

If you want to keep the original data but want to mask sensitive data only for specific people, you can leverage the Dynamic Data Masking feature:

Understanding Dynamic Data Masking — Snowflake Documentation:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-column-ddm-intro.html

Dynamic Data Masking is a feature allowing you to apply dynamic transformations with a query or a UDF to a table based on the current context (account, user, role, tag, etc.) by attaching a "Masking Policy" that you can arbitrarily define.

Below are examples of how you can mask the data with CTAS and Dynamic Data Masking.

**Sample data/masking UDF preparation**

```sql
create or replace table data (
  first_name varchar,
  last_name varchar,
  email varchar,
  address varchar,
  address2 varchar,
  address3 varchar,
  dob varchar
);

insert into data values
('Mike', 'Johnson', 'mike@gmail.com', '1650 Jackson St', 'Apt 704', null, '09/10'),
('John', 'Dunn', 'john101@gmail.com', '320 Day St', null, null, '01/20'),
('Bill', 'Rinitin', 'rinitin@gmail.com', '108 Marietta Dr', null, null, '04/11'),
('Chris', 'Talbot', 'chris2@gmail.com', '401 Harrison St', null, null, '07/17'),
('Teresa', 'Middleton', 'teresa.middleton@yahoo.com', '181 Fremont St', 'Unit 62C', null, '11/21'),
;

create or replace function udf_mask_name (name varchar)
returns varchar
language sql
as $$
    select left(name, 1) || repeat('*', len(name)-1)
$$;

create or replace function udf_mask_email (email varchar)
returns varchar
language sql
as $$
    select left(split_part(email, '@', 1), 1) ||
           repeat('*', len(split_part(email, '@', 1))-1) ||
           '@' ||
           split_part(email, '@', 2)
$$;

create or replace function udf_mask_dob (dob varchar)
returns varchar
language sql
as $$
    select split_part(dob, '/', 1) ||
           '/' ||
           repeat('*', len(split_part(dob, '/', 2)))
$$;
```

**Example 1: CTAS**

```sql
create or replace table data_masked (
  first_name varchar,
  last_name varchar,
  email varchar,
  address varchar,
  address2 varchar,
  address3 varchar,
  dob varchar
) as
select
    udf_mask_name(first_name),
    udf_mask_name(last_name),
    udf_mask_email(email),
    address, address2, address3,
    udf_mask_dob(dob)
from data
;

select * from data_masked;
/*
FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   EMAIL   ADDRESS ADDRESS2    ADDRESS3    DOB
M***    J****** m***@gmail.com  1650 Jackson St Apt 704     09/**
J***    D***    j******@gmail.com   320 Day St          01/**
B***    R****** r******@gmail.com   108 Marietta Dr         04/**
C****   T*****  c*****@gmail.com    401 Harrison St         07/**
T*****  M********   t***************@yahoo.com  181 Fremont St  Unit 62C        11/**
*/
```

**Example 2: Dynamic Data Masking**

```sql
create or replace masking policy mp_mask_name as
(val varchar) returns varchar ->
    case
        when current_role() = 'ACCOUNTADMIN' then val
        else udf_mask_name(val)
    end
;

create or replace masking policy mp_mask_email as
(val varchar) returns varchar ->
    case
        when current_role() = 'ACCOUNTADMIN' then val
        else udf_mask_email(val)
    end
;

create or replace masking policy mp_mask_dob as
(val varchar) returns varchar ->
    case
        when current_role() = 'ACCOUNTADMIN' then val
        else udf_mask_dob(val)
    end
;

alter table data modify column first_name set masking policy mp_mask_name;
alter table data modify column last_name set masking policy mp_mask_name;
alter table data modify column email set masking policy mp_mask_email;
alter table data modify column dob set masking policy mp_mask_dob;

use role accountadmin;
select * from data;
/*
FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   EMAIL   ADDRESS ADDRESS2    ADDRESS3    DOB
Mike    Johnson mike@gmail.com  1650 Jackson St Apt 704     09/10
John    Dunn    john101@gmail.com   320 Day St          01/20
Bill    Rinitin rinitin@gmail.com   108 Marietta Dr         04/11
Chris   Talbot  chris2@gmail.com    401 Harrison St         07/17
Teresa  Middleton   teresa.middleton@yahoo.com  181 Fremont St  Unit 62C        11/21
*/

use role nonadminrole;
select * from data;
/*
FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   EMAIL   ADDRESS ADDRESS2    ADDRESS3    DOB
M***    J****** m***@gmail.com  1650 Jackson St Apt 704     09/**
J***    D***    j******@gmail.com   320 Day St          01/**
B***    R****** r******@gmail.com   108 Marietta Dr         04/**
C****   T*****  c*****@gmail.com    401 Harrison St         07/**
T*****  M********   t***************@yahoo.com  181 Fremont St  Unit 62C        11/**
*/
```

---